# billing schedule record creation on netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have written a script which creates a billing schedule record for items on the creation of sales order using afterSubmit() user event script.
The billing schedule record gets created for every item,but it also should be set in line level field 'billing schedule' of the sales order.details in [image: This is the field marked where i need billing schedule to set]attachment

```
var rec =nlapiCreateRecord('billingschedule');

            var res = itemname.substring(0, 40);
            rec.setFieldValue('name',res);
            rec.setFieldValue('initialamount',itemamount);
            rec.setFieldValue('numberremaining','5');
            rec.setFieldText('frequency','Daily');

                                var sub = nlapiSubmitRecord(rec,true);
                                if(sub!=null)
                                    {
                                        nlapiSetLineItemValue('item','billingschedule',i+1,sub);
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the record in afterSubmit, otherwise it's read-only.

```
var salesOrderId = nlapiGetRecordId();
var soRec = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', salesOrderId);
// DO YOUR BILLING SCHEDULE CREATION LINE WORK
var soLines = soRec.getLineItemCount('item');
// SS1 indexes start at 1
for (var x = 1; x <= soLines; x++) {
    var rec =nlapiCreateRecord('billingschedule');  
    var res = itemname.substring(0, 40);
    rec.setFieldValue('name',res);
    rec.setFieldValue('initialamount',itemamount);
    rec.setFieldValue('numberremaining','5');
    rec.setFieldText('frequency','Daily');
    var sub = nlapiSubmitRecord(rec,true);
    if(sub!=null) {
        soRec.setLineItemValue('item','billingschedule', x, sub);
    }
}
// Submit the record to save the values
 nlapiSubmitRecord(soRec);
```

Comment: Thanks.It helped.How to attach that created billing schedule with SO record. i mean how to pass internal id of SO to the record created?